# Executing python function in postgres

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm trying to run a python function on the cursor.execute parameter but it just throws me this error.
I'm using psycopg2

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cliente.py", line 55, in <module>
cursorDB.execute(get_datos_animal('falsa'))
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "falsa" does not exist
LINE 1: ...e, clasificacion FROM animales WHERE animales.hierro = falsa
```

and my python function is this one

```
def get_datos_animal(hierro_v):
return "SELECT hierro, registro, nombre, fecha_nacimiento, raza, sexo, hierro_madre, hierro_padre, clasificacion FROM animales WHERE animales.hierro = " + str(hierro_v)
```

any idea what i´m doing wrong?

Have several functions like this with same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In postgres if you pass value without quotes it will treat that as column name.

Try this:

```py
def get_datos_animal(hierro_v):
return "SELECT hierro, registro, nombre, fecha_nacimiento, raza, sexo, hierro_madre, hierro_padre, clasificacion FROM animales WHERE animales.hierro = '"+str(hierro_v)+"'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the automatic parameter quoting [provided by your connection](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) to ensure that values in queries are always quoted correctly, and to avoid SQL injection attacks.

```
stmt = """SELECT hierro, registro, nombre, fecha_nacimiento, raza, sexo, hierro_madre, hierro_padre, clasificacion 
                 FROM animales 
                 WHERE animales.hierro = %s"""

cursor.execute(stmt, (hierro_v,))
```